# Split a CSV file into multiple files with header and given number of records

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd, split

I have a huge CSV file that I need to split into small CSV files, keep headers in each file and make sure that all records are kept. For example, here is the original file:

```
 ID    Date   
 1     01/01/2010
 1     02/01/2010
 2     01/01/2010 
 2     05/01/2010
 2     06/01/2010
 3     06/01/2010
 3     07/01/2010
 4     08/01/2010
 4     09/01/2010
```

If I split the file right, I should see the first 5 records in data_1.csv and the last 4 records in data_2.csv.

The code I have only splits by rows and does not keep the header. I don't know how to modify it:

```
 @echo off
 setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 set limit=5
 set file=data.csv
 set lineCounter=1
 set filenameCounter=1


 set name=
 set extension=

 for %%a in (%file%) do (
set "name=%%~na"
set "extension=%%~xa"
 )

 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
set splitFile=!name!-part!filenameCounter!!extension!
if !lineCounter! gtr !limit! (
    set /a filenameCounter=!filenameCounter! + 1
    set lineCounter=1
    echo Created !splitFile!.
)
echo %%a>> !splitFile!

set /a lineCounter=!lineCounter! + 1
)
```

Comment: Your code does not match the description of your example.

Comment: The example does not show a **C**SV (guess what the **C** stands for). Anyway, you could use [`set /P`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)`HEADER=""`[`<`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)`"data.csv"` to get the header, [`echo`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) and [`>`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to get it written to the other files; then use [`findstr /B "\<[0-9][0-9]*\>"`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), together with [`>>`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), to get the data filtered by the `ID` columns and output...

Comment: @aschipfl. Thank you very much for your comment. But since I am new to bach, where should I write those commands? Also, I don't know why, when I open cmd.exe the program says that it cannot find the file. It was able to find it yesterday. Do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: I guess I misread the question, so the `findstr` stuff is just wrong; see my answer (shortly)...

Comment: @Yelena, I tried to edit the question so that title and body match -- please feel free to correct it when I did something wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method similar to yours using a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to read the input file. The performance is not quite good however, because each output file is opened and closed for every single line written:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"   & rem // (first command line argument is input file)
set /A "_LIMIT=5" & rem // (number of records or rows per output file)

rem // Split file name:
set "NAME=%~dpn1" & rem // (path and file name)
set "EXT=%~x1"    & rem // (file name extension)

rem // Split file into multiple ones:
set "HEADER=" & set /A "INDEX=0, COUNT=0"
rem // Read file once:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    rem // Read header if not done yet:
    if not defined HEADER (
        set "HEADER=%%L"
    ) else (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Compute line index, previous and current file count:
        set /A "PREV=COUNT, COUNT=INDEX/_LIMIT+1, INDEX+=1"
        rem // Write header once per output file:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if !PREV! lss !COUNT! (
            > "!NAME!_!COUNT!!EXT!" echo/!HEADER!
        )
        rem // Write line:
        >> "!NAME!_!COUNT!!EXT!" echo/!LINE!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

To accomplish your task you do not even need a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html); rather you could use [`set /P`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), together with [input redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), in a [`for /L` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html), like this (see all the explanatory comments):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"   & rem // (first command line argument is input file)
set /A "_LIMIT=5" & rem // (number of records or rows per output file)

rem // Split file name:
set "NAME=%~dpn1" & rem // (path and file name)
set "EXT=%~x1"    & rem // (file name extension)

rem // Determine number of lines excluding header:
for /F %%I in ('^< "%_FILE%" find /V /C ""') do set /A "COUNT=%%I-1"

rem // Split file into multiple ones:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Read file once:
< "!_FILE!" (
    rem // Read header (first line):
    set /P HEADER=""
    rem // Calculate number of output files:
    set /A "DIV=(COUNT-1)/_LIMIT+1"
    rem // Iterate over output files:
    for /L %%J in (1,1,!DIV!) do (
        rem // Write an output file:
        > "!NAME!_%%J!EXT!" (
            rem // Write header:
            echo/!HEADER!
            rem // Write as many lines as specified:
            for /L %%I in (1,1,%_LIMIT%) do (
                set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
                if defined LINE echo/!LINE!
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

The advantage of this method is that the input file as well as each output file is opened once only.

Comment: @ aschipfl, thank you so much. What should I change and how in your code? The number of records per each ID may change depending on how long the historical data is. For example, if I split my big file into 4 rows, the last observation will show up in the second file. I want to avoid this case.

Comment: it works for me. This is excellent. Thank you very much.All headers are correct. But now how can I do the filtering by ID?

Comment: how should I use findstr? Inside the loop?

Comment: You are welcome! *»For example, if I split my big file into 4 rows, the last observation will show up in the second file. I want to avoid this case.«* You have to clearly specify how this should be handled. Do you want each file to hold at least 4 records, so if there are less than 4 left, append them to the last file?

Comment: Concerning filtering: Again you need to clearly specify what you want. Do you want an output file to be created per each individual `ID` value? Does the `ID` value also be appended to the output file names? Anyway, I suppose you do some experiments, and if stuck, ask another question here...

Comment: I want to split the file based on distinct IDs, not necessarily lines. For example, the first file has 2 distinct IDs, but 5 lines; the second file has 2 distinct IDs, but 4 lines. I don't want to split file by each ID. There will be too many of them.

Comment: Also, tried to run the file this morning and apply it to my original data. But cmd gives me an error saying that it cannot find the file. I wonder why. Here is what I have: set "_FILE=sql_data.csv" set /A "_LIMIT=500000" The program and the original file are in the same folder.

Comment: Try with `set "_FILE=%~dp0sql_data.csv"` to force the batch file to search for the file in its parent directory. So you want to give a number of distinct IDs that each output file should contain? As I said, this is worth a new question...

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much for your help! :-)

Comment: Dear aschipfl, I am going to post a separate question but I am still wondering if you have any idea of how to divide a big file, say of 50K distinct ID in which each ID has about 1,000 observations, into smaller files by the number of IDs. I don't want to just separate by 1000 rows as I want to have all history per each ID in one file.

Comment: @Yelena, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49676347) is not a different question, it is really almost the same...