# Create a batch file to split big data by distinct IDs

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file, split

I have a huge CSV file (data.csv) that I need to split into small CSV files by certain number of distinct ID values (not by line) and make sure that all records per ID are kept. And also I need to make sure that the headers are kept. For example, here is the original file:

```
ID    Date   
1     01/01/2010
1     02/01/2010
2     01/01/2010
2     05/01/2010
2     06/01/2010
3     06/01/2010
3     07/01/2010
4     08/01/2010
4     09/01/2010
```

If I split the file after every 2 distinct ID values, I should see the first 5 records in data_1.csv and the last 4 records in data_2.csv.

The code I have is .bat and only splits by the number of rows. I don't know how to modify it and am willing to consider other options, like PowerShell.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~dp0data.csv"   & rem // (first command line argument is   input    file)
set /A "_LIMIT=5" & rem // (number of records or rows per output file)

rem // Split file name:
set "NAME=data" & rem // (path and file name)
set "EXT=%~x1.csv"    & rem // (file name extension)

rem // Split file into multiple ones:
set "HEADER=" & set /A "INDEX=0, COUNT=0"
rem // Read file once:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    rem // Read header if not done yet:
    if not defined HEADER (
        set "HEADER=%%L"
    ) else (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Compute line index, previous and current file count:
        set /A "PREV=COUNT, COUNT=INDEX/_LIMIT+1, INDEX+=1"
        rem // Write header once per output file:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        >&2 echo !INDEX!; !PREV!, !COUNT!
        if !PREV! lss !COUNT! (
            > "!NAME!_!COUNT!!EXT!" echo/!HEADER!
        )
        rem // Write line:
        >> "!NAME!_!COUNT!!EXT!" echo/!LINE!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: Add the powershell tag to get help using a built-in tool more suited to the job.

Comment: @Compo The PowerShell tag is expected to go with some actual Powershell code.

Comment: questions 1) there are four distinct id's in your sample, shouldn't it generate four files? 2) Is it a required that this has to be a batch file?

Comment: Hi Kevin, no. I don't need to have separate files for each ID. I need instead to be able to set up the number of distinct ID, say 2, per each file.

Comment: @yelena - could you use Powershell or C# instead of a batch file?

Comment: @kevin. Unfortunately, I don't have it here at work. We're very limited in resources. All I have is R and have access to DOS.

Comment: @Yelena, what OS are you using? DOS has not been included with Windows for many years. Also, If you didn't want a PowerShell option why did you add the tag, _shortly before Ansgar removed it again_?

Comment: @Yelena - both are available for free depending on your OS, and unless you are running a very old unsupported OS it should not be a problem. This would be trivial to solve in Powershell or C#, and much more efficient because I believe a DOS batch file would need to open the complete file in memory.

Comment: @Kevin.Sure. What would be the best for this task? C#? I have Windows. And what version should I donwload?

Comment: @Yelena, which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @Yelena - You would get many different answers on what is best for the task. I would create a C# console application. You could start with https://code.visualstudio.com/ , if you are writing simple apps that will meet your needs. You could also write in Notepad and compile at the command prompt or download Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

Comment: @Compo. Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: Because you are running Windows 7, Visual Studio Code will not work. You can download 2013 Community Edition using this link https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: This question contains the same description as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49546165) with different title and code. If you want a separate file for each `ID` value, please adapt the question accordingly by [edit]ing it. Anyway, please clarify...

Comment: @Yelena, are you aware that PowerShell is included with that Operating System? Are you sure that your 'limited resources' excludes it? Have you tried opening or running it?

Comment: @Compo. You're right. Thank you very much. I have PowerShell on my computer. Is there a way to do the split in PowerShell then?

Comment: @Yelena, I tried to edit the question so that the goal becomes clearer -- please let me know when I did something wrong and feel free to correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided have *no relation* to the problem you described, so it doesn't makes much sense to use it as base...

The Batch file below do what you requested in the problem description:

**EDIT**: *Code modified to use semicolon as delimiter*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "distinctIDs=2"

set "lastID="
set /A "newIDs=-1, file=0"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%a in (data.csv) do (
   if not defined header (
      set "header=%%a;%%b"
   ) else (
      if "%%a" neq "!lastID!" (
         set "lastID=%%a"
         set /A newIDs+=1, newFile=newIDs%%distinctIDs
         if !newFile! equ 0 (
            set /A file+=1
            > data_!file!.csv echo !header!
         )
      )
      >> data_!file!.csv echo %%a;%%b
   )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for positing the code. But, apparently, I do smth wrong. My file data.csv still is divided into 5 parts. For example, data_3.csv has ID:= 2,3 and Date:= 6/1/2010, 6/1/2010. What I do is I save all files in one directory like your code with .bat extension and data.csv and simply click on Open.

Comment: Okay, for some reason, when data.csv is saved as a txt file, both codes work fine!  I guess I need to find where to change the delimiters. Thank you SO much again!

Comment: I have one more question. It the original file is in a .txt format with ";" delimiter, how should your code be modified to do the split?

Comment: You should note that we have _not_ access to your data, but just to the data you posted here as an example. If your posted data is not the same as the real data, then the program is likely to fail... **Note**: a csv file _is_ a text file!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am reading about <TAB> and <SPACE> as delimiters for batch files but still have a question: If my data is saved as a .txt file and looks like: ID;Date so that there is a ";" between the observations, how should I modify the code. I tried ^;^ and %%; and simply ; but nothing works.

Comment: As I said, we have not access to your data, but just to the data you post here. Why you had not posted your _real data_ here (in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49676347/edit)) until now? Do you expect that we _correct your wrong data_ based on a simple detail you gave _in a comment_? **`:(`** It would be much simpler if you just post your real data... Anyway, I modified the code _assuming_ that the columns are delimited by semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to write a certain amount of distinct `ID` numbers in each output file and the input file `data.csv` has got these values sorted as shown in your sample data, the following batch file could work for you:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"   & rem // (first command line argument is input file)
set /A "_LIMIT=2" & rem // (number of distinct values in first column per output file)

rem // Split file name:
set "NAME=%~dpn1" & rem // (path and file name)
set "EXT=%~x1"    & rem // (file name extension)

rem // Split file into multiple ones:
set "HEADER=" & set "OLD=" & set /A "INDEX=-1, COUNT=0"
rem // Read file once:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    rem // Read header if not done yet:
    if not defined HEADER (
        set "HEADER=%%L"
    ) else (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Split off value in first column:
        for /F "tokens=1" %%I in ("%%L") do (
            set "NEW=%%I"
            rem // Compute value index:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if not "!NEW!"=="!OLD!" (
                endlocal
                set /A "INDEX+=1"
            ) else endlocal
            rem // Compute previous and current file count:
            set /A "PREV=COUNT, COUNT=INDEX/_LIMIT+1"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Write header once per output file:
            if !PREV! lss !COUNT! (
                > "!NAME!_!COUNT!!EXT!" echo/!HEADER!
            )
            rem // Write line:
            >> "!NAME!_!COUNT!!EXT!" echo/!LINE!
            endlocal
            set "OLD=%%I"
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Hi aschipfl, thank you for posting the code. But it does not work, unfortunately. It creates five files and splits ID = 2 into two separate files.

Comment: Hm... it works for me; did you *copy* the code correctly? did you regard my assumption of sorted `ID` values?

Comment: Thank you SO much! Your code works indeed if I save my data as a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that all those files must be either TAB or SPACE delimited to have all those .bat files to work. If the files are ";" delimited, then (1) we should first replace ";" with a TAB and (2) run either aschipfl's or Aacini's codes. Both work with .txt TAB delimited files. Here is a code to do part (1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Get a tab character
for /f tokens^=^*^ delims^= %%t in ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x09"') do set "tab=%%t" 

rem For each line in text file, replace ; with a tab    
(for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (data_new.txt) do (
    set "line=%%l"  
    echo !line:;=%tab%!
)) > data_new_tab.txt

endlocal
```

Comment: No. You made a bad mistake here. The codes posted in this question works with SPACE delimited files because the posted example data use spaces as delimiter. As a matter of fact, the codes would be simpler if the delimiter is a semicolon (or _one_ space) instead of _several_ spaces as the posted data have. Why you didn't posted the real data in first place? We don't know, but it is funny that instead of _clarify your error_ about the wrong posted data (and post the real data), you are proposing a method to convert the real data into the wrong one in order to use the same codes!

Comment: I also want to clarify a fundamental error you have in your descriptions: a .csv file IS a text file. There is no way to save a .csv file in a format that it is not a text file. If you do so, then the saved file is _NOT_ a .csv file. **Important**: Batch code can _only_ process TEXT FILES. There is no way that Batch code can process any other type of file! Batch code can process .csv files because .csv files ARE text files. In other words: the _standard_ way to create an edit a .csv file is via a text editor, like Windows Notepad.

Comment: CSV stands for Comma Separated Values, so a .csv file must have commas as delimiters, although other character _different than space_ may also be used, like semicolon...

Comment: @Aacini. Thank you very much for modifying the code and also explaining the way batch files work. It does really help me understand the whole process. Thank you again!